# How do you gather terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A very basic question here:

Given $(x^{1/4}-y^{1/4})(x^{3/4}+x^{1/2}y^{1/4}+x^{1/4}y^{1/2}+y^{3/4})$

How after factorisation  using do you gather terms? I've managed to get down to

$x+x^{3/4}y^{1/4} + x^{1/4}y^{3/4} - y^{1/4}x^{3/4} - x^{1/2}y^{1/2} - x^{1/4}y^{3/4} -y$.

How can I evaluate this step by step to $x-y$ as I'm a little unsure on the rules for gathering terms given $x$ and $y$ multiplying each other at each summation.

Comment: Please use LateX, it makes everything more readable.

Comment: You're missing a $x^{1/2}y^{1/2}$ term in the second equation. From there you can just notice that each term (other than $x$ and $-y$) occurs twice, with different signs so they all cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you missed one term, you should expect $2 \times 4 = 8$, you only get $7$.

Then you should see that everything except $x - y$ cancel in pairs.

But to make your life simpler, write $a = x^{1/4}, b = y^{1/4}$, and rewrite your expression as
\begin{align}
&(a - b) (a^{3} + a^{2} b + a b^{2} + b^{3}) 
\\=&
\begin{matrix}
a^{4} &+& a^{3} b &+& a^{2} b^{2} &+& a b^{3}\\
&-& a^{3} b &-& a^{2} b^{2} &-& a b^{3} &-& b^{4}
\end{matrix}
\\=& 
a^{4} - b^{4}
\end{align}
where you see clearly the terms cancelling in pairs. (In the two-row expression, the first row is the expansion of $a (a^{3} + a^{2} b + a b^{2} + b^{3})$, the second one the expansion of $-b(a^{3} + a^{2} b + a b^{2} + b^{3})$.)

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Comment: What would happen if they hypothetically didn't cancel out? How would you resolve a^2b-a^3b for example?

Comment: @peter_gent, I don't think you can do more than collecting as $a^{2} b(1 - a)$.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any further rules for collecting terms?:)

Comment: @peter_gent, just to understand the general direction, do you have some particular examples in mind?

Comment: not any specific ones, no I'm afraid.